# Optimal ordering - Dynamic programming on subsets

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, np-hard

We have a set T of n elements and m subsets $R_i \subset T i = 1,...,m$.
The $S_i$ are not assumed to be different. We also define an ordering of T, a one-to-one mapping $\pi$ of $T$ onto the set of integers ${1,...n}$. That is, every $\pi(v)$ is an integer from 1 to n and all $\pi(v), v \in T$ are distinct. For a set $R \subset T$ and an ordering of $\pi$ of $V$, let $l_\pi(S)$ and $r_\pi(S)$ denote, respectively, the smallest and largest value $\pi(v)$ among all $v \in S$. The problem is to find an ordering $\pi$ that minimizes $\sum_{i=1}^m (r_\pi(S_i) - l_\pi(S_i))$.

This problem is NP-hard but is in FPT and can be solved with dynamic programming on subsets in $O^*(2^n)$

The idea here is to optimize the ordering of the first $k$ items and then go from $k$ to $k+1$ items and prove that the time complexity does not change when doing so.

But how do we optimize the ordering for the first $k$ items in just $O^*(2^n)$ time? It seems like the same problem as the initial one to me.

Comment: Do you have a reference where you read the problem can be solved in $O^*(2^n)$ time?

Comment: The problem was stated together with that information. Note the difference between $O(2^n)$ and $O^*(2^n)$ where in the latter, all polynomial factors can be omitted.

Comment: "The $S_i$ are not assumed to be different." What are the $S_i$? You have not mentioned them before. Did you maybe mean the $R_i$ ? If so please edit accordingly.